# Epson receipt buffered printing issue

Tags: api, printing, sdk, epson, receipt

I am using Epson TM-S9000 SDK to print receipt from a web page.
C# console app. Using

> `m_objProperty.BufferedPrint(PrintBuffer.MF_PRT_BUFFERING)`

It prints fine, but clears the print buffer right afterwards.
How can I print multiple copies of the same receipt in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no straightforward way of the buffered printing for multiple copies.
I figured I can use only `PrintText()` from the SDK, for example:

```
int numberOfCopies = a;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCopies; i++)
        {
            myMFDevice.SetPrintAlignment(Alignment.MF_PRINT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            myMFDevice.PrintText(strBuilder.ToString(), myDecorate);
            myMFDevice.AutoCutRollPaper(AutoCutType.AUTOCUT_FEEDANDCUT);
        }
```